# Using bos fbx Error: "no module named UMIO"

Tags: add-on

Using v2.77a
Should I go for a clean install? That is all I can think of doing.

Message: 
[image: error message]

Comment: import_bos_fbx.py isn't part of Blender, best re-install.

Comment: Clean install of Blender? I tried to reinstall bos fbx nothing changed.

Comment: This isn't an issue with Blender, you might be best to report this to the add-on author.

Comment: This is Blender not able to install an add-on or use an add-on properly. I'd say it is a issue with Blender.

Comment: I installed 2.76b the version bos fbx used to work and now no problems so definitely a problem with the latest version of Blender v2.77a

Comment: Whatever the case, the missing module is not part of Blender, so this isnt a problem with Blender.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it seems that you are using the BOS FBX importer with Blender 2.77.

The newest version of this add-on (at the time of this post) relies on precompiled libraries for Python 3.4 (see `scripts/addons/io_scene_bos_fbx/win64bit/python34/UMIO.pyd`) but Blender 2.77 ships with Python 3.5, so it won't be able to find the UMIO module.

```
Name                          Version
--------------------------------------------------
Blender 2.76                  Python 3.4
Blender 2.77                  Python 3.5
Blender 2.78                  Python 3.5

BOS FBX Importer 2015-07-04   Python 3.4
```

You need to either keep around a copy of Blender 2.76 to use this add-on with or ask the author to provide a newer version for Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

In file `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_bos_fbx\import_bos_fbx.py`

Add these code under `um_folder = os.path.join(um_folder, "win64bit")` **and** `um_folder = os.path.join(um_folder, "win32bit")` :

`if sys.version_info[:2] == (3, 5):
um_folder = os.path.join(um_folder, "python34")`

This should be a temporary method to solve the problem.